# failed to compile: Parsing error unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

Failed to Compile: Parsing error unexpected token. The error is on line 20

I am new to React I was following a Brad Traversy tutorial and cant seem to debug this code error. I included the full code below.

```
  ./src/Components/AddProject.js
  Line 20:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  18 |     e.preventDefault();
  19 |   }
> 20 |   if(this.refs.title.value === ''){
     |      ^
  21 |       alert('Title is required');
  22 |     } else {
  23 |       this.setState({newProject:{
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message and stack trace if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot attach flying code in an ES6 JavaScript Class. 
It actually doesn't mean anything.

A ES6 Javascript Class will only accept constructor, fields and methods.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Are you sure that the code below the line of the syntax error shouldn't be wrapped into a method or into `render()` ?

Comment: link to Github file is here https://github.com/jedidrew42/projectmanager/blob/master/src/Components/AddProject.js

Comment: This code will not work. I'm pretty sure there is an extra bracket line 19. And then one of the two `e.preventDefault();`  become superficial.